# Accessing Data using df['foo'] missing data for pattern searching python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

So I have this function which takes in one row from dataframe and matches the pattern 
and add it to the data. Since pattern search needs input to be string, I am forcing it with str(). However, if I do that it cuts off my url after certain point.

I figured out if I force it using ix function

```
str(data.ix[0,'url'])
```

It does not cut off any and gets me what I want. Also, if I use `str(data.ix[:'url'])`,
it also cuts off after some point.

Problem is I cannot specify the index position inside the ix function as I plan to iterate by row using apply function. Any suggestion?

```
def foo (data):
    url = str(data['url'])
    m = re.search(r"model=(?P<model>\w+)&id=\d+&make=(?P<make>\w+)", url)
    if m:
        data['make'] = m.group("make")
        data['model'] = m.group("model")
        return data
```

Comment: Can you post raw data and example code that demonstrates this 'cutting' off

Comment: Also, please tell us your pandas version just in case

Answer (score 3):

Iterating row-by-row is a last resort. It's almost always slower, less readable, and less idiomatic.

Fortunately, there is an easy way to do what you want to do. Check out the [DataFrame.str.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#extracting-substrings) method, added in version 0.13 of pandas.

Something like this...

```
pattern = r'model=(?P<model>\w+)&id=\d+&make=(?P<make>\w+)'
extracted_data = data.str.extract(pattern)
```

The result, `extracted_data` will be a new DataFrame with columns named 'model' and 'make', inferred from the named groups in your regex pattern.

Join it to your original DataFrame, and you're done.

```
data = data.join(extracted_data)
```